# Passing an array to a subroutine encloses it in another array?

Tags: arrays, perl, subroutine

I noticed that when I pass an array to my subroutine it seems like it gets encapsulated by another array (so two levels, while the initial is only one).

I know that using references to arrays is better, but I'm wondering in this specific case why it is not working as expected.

#### Code example:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;

sub testSub {
    my (@arr) = (@_);
    print Dumper \@arr;
}

my @testArray = ();
push @testArray, {
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'urls' => [ 'www.example.com' ]
};

print Dumper @testArray;

foreach my $item ( @testArray ) {

    my @urls = testSub( $item->{'urls'} );
}
```

#### output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'urls' => [
                      'www.example.com'
                    ],
          'key1' => 'value1',
          'key2' => 'value2'
        };
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'www.example.com'
          ]
        ];
```

Comment: Why do you think so? `testSub` prints the *reference* to the array, as you used the backslash, and returns 1 if the print is successful.

Comment: The first level comes from the Dumper (you are passing a reference). The second level comes from the fact that `[ 'www.example.com' ]`  also is a reference to an array. So in the subroutine `@arr`  is not what you expect in this case. You expect it to be `('www.example.com')`, but it is `([www.example.com])` .

Comment: So the array is an "anonymous" array here, right? So the hash only has a reference to it. Is it actually possible for a hash key to have an array directly or can it only hold 1 dimensional data (for a specific key)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my @urls = testSub( $item->{'urls'}, 'abc' );

Result of Dumper in subrotine:
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'www.example.com'
          ],
          'abc'
        ];
```

Array passed by reference. Since at the time of compilation perl did not know what will be in the scalar `$item->{'urls'}`.

```
my @urls = testSub( @{ $item->{'urls'} }, 'abc' );

Result of Dumper in subrotine:
$VAR1 = [
          'www.example.com',
          'abc'
        ];
```

Now the compiler expects an array and turns it into a list.

Answer (score 1):

- You are passing `$item->{'urls'}` to your subroutine
- Your `Data::Dumper` output clearly shows that the hash element looks like this

  ```
  'urls' => [ 'www.example.com' ]
  ```
- When you call `testSub`, you are making an assignment that is equivalent to

  ```
  my @arr = ( [ 'www.example.com' ] );
  ```
- Your statement `print Dumper \@arr` passes an *array reference* to `Dumper`, so it displays

  ```
  [ [ 'www.example.com' ] ]
  ```

It would help your confusion if you were consistent in calling `Dumper`. `print Dumper @testArray` passes the contents of `@testArray` as individual parameters (although in this case the array has only a single element) while `print Dumper \@arr` passes an array reference as a *single parameter*, and is the better choice

Answer (score 0):

If you want `testSub` to receive a list of URLs, you must expand the *array* `$item->{urls}` into a *list* with `@{ ... }`:

```
my @urls = testSub( @{ $item->{'urls'} } );
```